# Bitbucket Server Backup Client in ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, repository, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, home-directory

Hi I am new to bitbucket backup process. I tried to backup the bitbucket server using the client by the typing the below line Example

```
java -Dbitbucket.password="admin" -Dbitbucket.user="admin" -Dbitbucket.baseUrl="http://localhost:7990" -Dbitbucket.home=path/to/bitbucket/home -Dbackup.home=path/to/backup-home -jar bitbucket-backup-client.jar
```

I am facing the below error but I entered the correct the username, password, URL and path locations. but I don't know what this error tells kindly help me to rectify the error

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors or other text. Copy the original text to the question (and edit with code edit tool)

Comment: "Invalid bean definition with name 'appHome' defined in class path..."

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have read, write and execute permission for user and usergroup to atlbitbucket user for that bitbucket-backup-client.jar file